# Jquery Ajax call runs into error "has already been loaded"

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

i make a jquery ajax call to get some html, and try to inject it in a DIV. The ajax call is successful; i tested that with an alarm within the "success" function. When i select the div, and try to inject the html via .html, the error "Uncaught Error: rails-ujs has already been loaded!" is thrown. I suspect that i need to strip the html header out of the response, but iam curios since i couldnt find anyone using this when i google the issue. Any idea ?

```
$.ajax({
url: "/qip_changes/4",
success: function(data){
    var temp = $("#modal_dialog")
    temp.html(data);}
});

Uncaught Error: rails-ujs has already been loaded!
at Object.Rails.start (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:350), <anonymous>:626:17)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:350), <anonymous>:675:15)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:350), <anonymous>:678:8)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:350), <anonymous>:679:6)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:350), <anonymous>:686:4)
at eval (<anonymous>)
at jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:350
at Function.globalEval (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:351)
at text script (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:10373)
at ajaxConvert (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:9333)
```

as requested here is the HTML i get. I think it tries to load the resources again, since the html head is included in the response. But I think this is a standard use-case, so how can i add my html body now to build the new div ? I removed a couple of lines from the head, but you get it..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Qipmatedevel</title>
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="iHpkgs5MnuprF/MSafLonZEsd+6OcrdLBxgIYdgLnL2IWeHpToeixf60mTw+ce2vLOsYimDPZwXmmxDR9C7k3g==" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/theme.self-830c3407ba1359ea36eee978235be14de5b78dacfa658a31226fe4f2b0faa7e7.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/core.self-e4bdefd3813c8a715955a6c65b9e730846dcae6a0576618563d635ff0b18a3ca.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/accordion.self-aa0730fc025317fed4feff2aa5fc07cba5a545dfc5c913a2984ba6f8695b29fb.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
.
.
.
.
<script src="/assets/qip_changes.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-3e52b2e0960c022373a99a81be2db0f03db9befe8798811b43ad82485b0e8966.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='qip_change_show'>
<br>
Render my test
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

so i think i found the issue. It is indeed that try to load the HTML including the HTML Header. I will need to check how to render my HTML on the server without the HTML header. Since iam new to rails, this can take some time, but i will update it here later

My issue was, that i tried to load a complete HTML view again, including all headers. I added a new Layout, which does not include any HTML headers, and render this when i build my view. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the semicolon on line 4:

```
$.ajax({
url: "/qip_changes/4",
success: function(data){
    var temp = $("#modal_dialog"); <--- Semicolon
    temp.html(data);}
});
```

But that wont solve the problem.
Can you post the html you want to load via ajax?

Comment: added the html in the question